# Detect when native iOS Music player change a song

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

Is there a way to detect when the native iOS `Music` app changes a song? of course while my app is in background.

I know there is the 
`MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification`, but my app doesn't uses a `MPMusicPlayerController` so I don't know how relevant it is.
My app uses a regular `AVPlayer` to play songs, and I would like the ability to detect if user started playing song from the `Music` app, while my app is in background.

I tried doing

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification:) name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification object:[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]];  

- (void)handleMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)not {
    NSLog(@"not %@", not);
}
```

but the notification didn't fired after changing a song.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749339/finding-out-what-song-is-playing-in-music-app/24749436#24749436

Comment: @troop231 I'm not sure if thats best practice, firing a timer while app is in background for unlimited time.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. Your app DOESNT remain active that long in background

Comment: @troop231 so you say anyway this will stop working after few seconds/minutes?

Comment: yes, because an app doesn't have but 7 minutes to run in the background